# Using grafana duration variable to resample prometheus data

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-variable

I have a Prometheus gauge metric `x` that models a rate per second. My goal is to create a Grafana dashboard that shows a bar chart for this rate and is generic over various levels of aggregation such as "average rate over the last 60min".

For a **fixed** duration such as 60min, this is straightforward. We take the average in Prometheus and multiple with the number of seconds in the time window:

```
avg_over_time( x[60m] ) * 60 * 60
```

With this fixed query, it is also easy to create a Grafana dashboard that shows a bar chart with one 'bar' per hour (setting 'Min step' to 60m) whose magnitude is defined by the query above.

I want to make this visualization generic over the time span over which the mean value is taken. To this end, I have defined a "duration" variable `$duration` in Grafana. However, I am stuck on how to formulate the prometheus query:

```
avg_over_time( x[$duration] ) * ???
```

Since `$duration` is not a number but a string such as `60m`, I can't simply take `$duration * 60` here. How can I convert the contents of `$duration` to a number of seconds?

Thank you!

Comment: Is this a metric that you're exposing yourself? Asking because if you exposed a COUNTER as opposed to a GAUGE, this would be a very trivial question to answer. Instead of the metric containing the actual rate, it should just contain the total number of requests. Then you can rate(metric[$__rate_interval]) for the RPS in any given duration.